# grep search count occurrences in number of files in recursive folder tree

Tags: search, grep

Say I have 1000 files in multiple recursive folders and say the string 'testing' is in 600 files and total number of mention of 'testing' within those 600 files is 750 times. Then -
I need something like "`750 matches across 600 files`"

I got close as -

```
grep -Rcl 'string' .
```

Which gives me name of every file but I just want the numbers.

and

```
grep -roh 'string' . | wc -w
```

Which gives me just the number of occurrences

Can you please let me have the whole command?

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify what number? I guess you mean number of occurrences per file, with the filename. Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1750396/edit) and add an example of the desired output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited the question and I hope maybe you wanted this clarifications. Thank you for your reply. @mashuptwice

Comment: I got the number of calls/occurrences with `grep -roh 'string' . | wc -w` and how can I get the number of files, not the file names just the number. Thank you. @Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with a single command, but you can combine multiple:

```
echo "$(grep -R asdf | wc -l) matches in $(grep -Rl asdf | wc -l) files"
```

outputs:

```
40 matches in 20 files
```